# BASH - execute command for all files with some extension

Tags: bash

I have to execute command in ***bash*** for all files in a folder with the extension ".prot'

The command is called "bezogener_Spannungsgradient" and it's called like that:

```
bezogener_Spannungsgradient filename.prot
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.prot -exec bezogener_Spannungsgradient {} \;
```

`-maxdepth <depth>` keeps `find` from recursing into subdirectories beyond the given depth.

`-name <pattern>` limits `find` to files matching the pattern. The escape is necessary to keep bash from expanding the `find` option into a list of matching files.

`-exec <cmd> {} \;` executes `<cmd>` on each found file (replacing `{}` with the filename). If the command is capable of processing a *list* of files, use `+` instead of `\;`.

I generally recommend becoming familiar with the lots of other [options of `find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find); it's one of the most underestimated tools out there. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
for f in *.prot; do
  bezogener_Spannungsgradient "$f"
done
```